# AJAX listener for Facebook Like Button

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, facebook, facebook-like

I have a few like buttons on my page and I would like to trigger a PHP script (via AJAX) when somebody "likes" or "doesn't like".

I see that when somebody "likes," a POST and a GET are triggered. When somebody does a "doesn't like," just a post is triggered. This could be a way to differentiate both actions.

How could I intercept these triggered actions ?

Is there a way to get the parameters of the post ?

Comment: The POST response is different in case of "like" or "doesn't like". If I could read it it would make the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [`FB.Event` API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) in the Facebook Javascript SDK, the `subscribe` function should let you do what you want.

From the documentation, here's a sample for your usecase:

```js
// new like
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);

// removed like
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove',
    function(response) {
        alert('You unliked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);
```

Comment: Note that for this to work you have to use the XFMBL Like button, not the iframe/HTML5 versions.

Comment: @ceejayoz can you verify that for HTML5? The iframe version definitely is a no-go, but I would have guessed the HTML5 buttons could be picked up successfully.

Comment: Sometimes the alert appears, sometimes not. Is there a cache issue to solve ?

Comment: @HappyLearner No, I would guess that your event subscriptions are firing before the page is rendering, giving you a race condition. Throw the event subscriptions after FB.init, and inside a `$(document).ready()` block.

Comment: I am doing that :

   $(document).ready(function() {
   
   FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  alert('Your name is ' + response.name);
 });
   
// new like
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);

// removed like
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove',
    function(response) {
        alert('You unliked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);

  });

Comment: @HappyLearner I don't see a `FB.init` call. I [replicated this in a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JimmySawczuk/KJv79/) and couldn't replicate your problem.

Comment: sorry, here it is (part 1) :

<script> 
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '211422772316717', // App ID
      channelUrl : 'http:localhost:8080/likebooster/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
  };

Comment: Part 2

$(document).ready(function() {

// new like
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);

// removed like
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove',
    function(response) {
        alert('You unliked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);

  });

Comment: it never works in Chrome, almost never in firefox and sometimes in IE

Comment: Your issue is the async init call: sometimes it happens before the page renders, sometimes it doesn't. Check my jsFiddle again and I think you'll see that's the main difference in our code. By the way, usually, we don't put that amount of code in a comment; move it to a jsFiddle or put it in the body of the question.

Comment: I don't think so; it's because your `FB.init` call and your `$(document).ready` call are happening asynchronously, which is to say they're sometimes acting out of order.

Comment: I have updated the code in Fiddle, It's working on it but not in localhost. I am very sorry, i don't find a solution..

Comment: I just noticed the `channelUrl`, that won't work with `localhost`. You shouldn't need that for this though.

Comment: It's the same, it just works in IE one time, then I refresh and it doesn't work anymore